# Read and output a matrix file in bash

Tags: bash

let's say I have a matrix.txt file as described below

```
3   4   2   2   5
1   2   3   7   6
3   5   6   7   5
9   0   8   6   5
7   6   8   9   5
```

Now I want to read and output the first 3 rows and 3 columns in bash, would someone help me how to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `awk 'NF=3; NR==3{exit}' file`?

Comment: This question is considerable more ambiguous than you might intend it to be. Are you asking for one mechanism to emit all columns of the first three rows, and a separate mechanism to emit all rows of the first three columns? Are you asking for a single output with only 9 items, consisting of three rows of three columns each? Showing your desired output would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR>3{exit} {print $1,$2,$3}' matrix.txt
3 4 2
1 2 3
3 5 6
```

`NR`: number of rows.

`$1,$2,$3`: first, second and third columns

To print `n` rows and `m` columns:

```
$ awk -v row=3 -v col=3 'NR>row{exit} {for (i=1; i<=col; i++)printf $i" "; print ""}' matrix.txt
3 4 2 
1 2 3 
3 5 6
```

Comment: Wouldn't `NR>3{exit}` be a bit better? :)

Comment: Thanks, how about printing n lines, m col?

Answer (score 0):

Using cut is perhaps easiest

```
cut -d' ' -f1-3 matrix.txt | head -3
```